# 3d object created from motion trackers is rotating the opposite direction; how to correct?

Tags: transforms, tracking

It's my first attempt to use motion tracking and the VSE in Blender; I decided to use a clip from a movie to mess around with and try to get the hang of it. I think I am getting very close to achieving what I want (to add a 3d object that matches the rotation and movement of the character on screen). A problem I am having I will try to show with two images, if video is needed I will gladly stream on OpenVFX or Blender discord channels.

The character in frame one is facing a little to left, then by the end on frame 49 is facing more-so to the right. My trackers look fine and dandy on the 2d view after a lot of manual keyframing.

I used the "3D Markers to Mesh" button, and then turned those points into a mesh with the "Convex Hull" option under Mesh in edit mode. Additionally, these track points were set to a separate object than the camera, so once I went to 3d view I set an object solver between the object and the camera. I now should be able to attach a 3d object to this mesh and have it match the movements of the character. The problem I am having though is that the rotation of this mesh is going in the opposite direction (rotating right to left). Is there a feature or option somewhere that I missed that will correct this when I solve the motion trackers? Thank you in advance if you have anything that could help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added one large tracker across the chest and set it to perspective. It's still not perfectly smooth, but the rotation is correct now. [image]